# Determine which shortcut is installed first

Tags: wix

I am installing many multiple shortcuts and have noticed the first installed seems to appear as soon as you click the start button and then the remaining shortcuts are under All Programs - Product Name. My problem is that I would like my main product to be in the start menu as a large icon. One of my other shortcuts is showing at the minute. This is my code:

This shortcut should only be in All Programs - Product Name - Logger Folder. Which it is but it is also on the main start menu.

```
  <Component Id="Logger1Shortcut" Guid="31987043-21B3-49F7-ADA2-A2BBC6FA446D">
    <Condition><![CDATA[(NUMLOGGERS >= "1") AND (NUMLOGGERS <> "0")]]></Condition>
    <Shortcut Id="Logger1Shortcut" Directory="ProgramMenuSubFolder" Name="LOGGER 1" Icon="stand_cf_Logger1" IconIndex="0" Target="[BIN]stand_cf.exe">
      <Icon Id="stand_cf_Logger1" SourceFile="$(var.Bin)\stand_cf.exe"/>
    </Shortcut>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Measuresoft\[PRODUCTNAME]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
  </Component>
```

This is my component with the main application:

```
  <Component Id="MainApplicationShortcut" Guid="C130E034-BDC0-4700-A924-60C816AF6D01">
    <Shortcut Id="MainApp" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Orchestrator" Icon="mainmenu.exe" IconIndex="0" Target="[BIN]mainmenu.exe">
      <Icon Id="mainmenu.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Bin)\mainmenu.exe"/>
    </Shortcut>

    <Shortcut Id="ChannelMonitor" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Channel Monitor" Icon="mon_nt.exe" IconIndex="0" Target="[BIN]mon_nt.exe">
      <Icon Id="mon_nt.exe" SourceFile="$(var.Bin)\mon_nt.exe"/>
    </Shortcut>
    <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' Directory='ProgramMenuDir'/>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\Measuresoft\[PRODUCTNAME]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
  </Component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't determine the order in which shortcuts are installed. To achieve, what you want, you should do it the other way: mark all the secondary shortcuts with [`System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Just add [`ShortcutProperty`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_shortcutproperty.htm) element as the child of your `Shortcut`:

```
<Shortcut Id="ChannelMonitor" …>
    <Icon … />
    <ShortcutProperty Key="System.AppUserModel.ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall" />
</Shortcut>
```

Comment: Thank you, Am I correct in thinking this is not introduced until MSI 5.0 which only runs on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2? I need my installer to run on XP and Vista. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you are: [`MsiShortcutProperty` Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not supported on Vista/XP. Windows Installer simply ignores this table on unsupported systems. These properties are used only in Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2. Anyway you have to test it on XP and Vista.